# Slow execution of commands in Rstudio

Tags: r, performance, rstudio

I am experiencing some very annoying problems in Rstudio; simple commands that usually are executed instantaneously are sometimes taking 10-20 seconds to execute. When it happens seems to be random. For example, I can run "5+5" 10 times in a row just fine, but on the 11th try it takes 10-20 seconds to finish. Then it is fine for another 7 tries, and then it takes longer to finish again.

I have tried resetting Rstudios desktop state (https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-Desktop-s-State), but it didn`t help.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Torgeir

Comment: Report the issue to the RStudio support forum.

Comment: Ok, I`ll do that, thanks.